# How to page the lldb debugger help-text?

Tags: lldb

If I invoke the lldb help on a given topic, most of it flies off the screen.  Example:

```
(lldb) help expression
```

I can quit the debugger, and collect the help in typescript, but that's clumsy.  Does lldb have a pager, and if so, how is it used?

Comment: For such a verbose output it does seem strange that there isn't one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't currently a pager for the help command.  Feel free to file a bug on http://bugs.llvm.org requesting this.

Comment: It would be a real help. I'm trying to see if there is an easy mapping to a man page?